# Trusted development path in git with signatures

Tags: git, version-control, digital-signature, gnupg

I'd like to build a trusted path for software development. This
means that every change in to code must be signed by the author
and one reviewer, before being accepted. These signatures for the
changes must be verifiable at release time, or there must be some
other means of making sure the repository can not have been
tampered, or additional changes added.

The version control system that I am expecting to use for this is
git, but other options are also accepted. Signing can be via
GnuPG or SSL certificates.

The workflow I am thinking would be roughly:

1. Current verified trunk is branched
2. Changes are developed in the branch by one or more developers
3. One or more developers sign the changes made by the branch
4. A reviewer reviews and tests the changes
5. Reviewer signs the changes made by the branch
6. Branch is "merged" in to current verified trunk

Merging does not have to be foolproof such as that unreviewed
changes would need to be unmergeable to trunk - just that before
a release, there needs to be a way to check if there are any
unreviewed (unsigned) changes in trunk. And in general, tampering need not be prevented, only detected.

I'd like a short guide on how to set this up and how each operation is done. Once I get some pointers, I can figure out the specifics myself.

Also, I already know about 'git tag -s' technically, but I am unsure how to apply it to this particular problem.

Comment: There hasn't been any concrete answers giving all of the story yet, so I'm leaving it open. I am trying out some possibilities myself and if I come up with a concrete one, I will post the answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changes will not be signed until you tag.  Anything before that point can be verified by the author or by another out-of-band mechanism, but not from within git.

git can verify that a change's heritage is correct, but only the signed tag can verify the change itself is correct.

For your workflow, you may just find yourself tagging a lot.

Comment: It seems I will have to find out the concrete solution myself.

Comment: @Nakedible Note that as of [Git 1.7.9](https://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob_plain;f=Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.9.txt;hb=HEAD) individual commits can be signed with -S. And signatures can be viewed with the "--show-signature" option to "git log".

Comment: Thank you for the information. However, it would seem that -S works only when doing the commit, and commits can not be signed later on. I hope to be wrong about this, though.

Comment: you can sign afterwards but you need to rebase then on top of that commit, as signing changes the commit hash and that needs to be propagated for all of the next commits. it's inconvenient for older commits as you probably have already pushed them somewhere so you need to replace them on the remotes. however, this also means that the signature is valid for all of the future commits, you can trace the repo integrity having one signature per different development branches

Answer (score 0):

Git is a good candidate since:

- each commits are already signed
- the SHA1 key for each commit is enough to be sure the *all* repo has not been modified
- git tag -s can be used to sign a commit someone didn't make ([`git tag -m` is more explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064499/unable-to-see-a-list-of-git-tags/1064505#1064505))

So:

1. Current verified trunk is branched

   ```
   git checkout -b tag_for_last_verified_trunk_content test # branch test
   ```
2. Changes are developed in the branch by one or more developers

   ```
   [work...] git commit -s -m "dev1 comment" ...
   ```
3. One or more developers sign the changes made by the branch

   *Already done with their commits, by adding a Signed-of line at the end of the commit message*: see this page for **[explanation on the signed-off](http://kerneltrap.org/node/3180)** process.

   ```
   Signed-off-by: user name
   ```
4. A reviewer reviews and tests the changes

   ```
    git tag -m "testing" testing # refer to current commit, 
                                   allowing dev to go on with further changes
   ```
5. Reviewer signs the changes made by the branch

   ```
   git tag -m "tested" tested testing # put a tag on the same SHA1 than 
                                        the "testing" tag
   ```
6. Branch is "merged" in to current verified trunk

   ```
   git checkout trunk & git merge tested
   ```

---

[Cyryl Plotnicki-Chudyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559758/cyryl-plotnicki-chudyk) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423520/trusted-development-path-in-git-with-signatures/2423637#comment29818212_2423637) that, since git 1.7.9 (January 2012, almost 2 years after this answer), you can GPG-sign any commit you want, using `git commit -S`.
(See [commit ba3c69a9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ba3c69a9), refined more recently in [commit df45cb3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df45cb3ea31eee8ad1c763d1b8a35da87366017f))

Comment: I do not understand your explanation. How is each commit already signed? Sure, the commit contains the SHA1 for all of the repo, but nothing says the commit is made by the author given in the commit. I am unaware of any digital signatures being made to the commit?

Comment: @Nakedible: sorry, I did forget the `-s` option on the commit. Remember this is a very light-weight signed-off process (see the link I added in my answer, no "digital signatures" involved at this point, unlike `tag -s`)

Comment: Hey, actually since git v1.7.9 it's possible to GPG-sign any commit you want.
use `git commit -S` to do that

Comment: @CyrylPłotnicki-Chudyk Good point. I have included it in the answer, along with some reference to git commits which introduced that feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can sign your tag with your GPG key with -s option in tag  `git tag -s v0.1.0`:

> -s
>
> ```
>    Make a GPG-signed tag, using the default e-mail address's key
> ```

But you can't signed a commit.

Comment: As I said in my original question, I already know the -s option in git tag, but that does not solve the entire problem.

Comment: adding this comment also here;  
actually since git v1.7.9 it's possible to GPG-sign any commit you want.
use `git commit -S` to do that