# How can I list all tags in my Git repository by the date they were created?

Tags: git

I need some way to list all tags in my system by the date they were created but am not sure if I can get that data via git-log. Ideas?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to get the list of all tags _in order_ of there creation dates?

Comment: FYI **(1.)** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6269927/52074) is for listing ANNOTATED tags by date. **(2.)** For listing LIGHTWEIGHT tags by date, [go here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6900328/52074). **(3.)** For a helpful reminder on what is the difference between Git's lightweight vs annotated tags, [go here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4971746/52074).

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith: That's not quite correct. The difference is that (2) lists all tags by _commit date_ of the _tagged commit_, whereas this page gives solutions that sort by _date tagged_ (though only for annotated tags, since git doesn't store date tagged for lightweight tags).

Answer (score 281, accepted):

Sorting by tag creation date works with annotated and lightweight tags:

```
git for-each-ref --sort=creatordate --format '%(refname) %(creatordate)' refs/tags
```

Comment: Awesome. `git for-each-ref --format="%(taggerdate): %(refname)" --sort=-taggerdate --count=10 refs/tags` did exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: A solution by @DrorCohen which works for lightweight tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900328/git-command-to-show-all-lightweight-tags-creation-dates. Pasting here for easy reference: git log --tags --simplify-by-decoration --pretty="format:%ai %d"

Comment: Can use `%(contents)` to add in annotation if needed, e.g. `git for-each-ref --sort='*authordate' --format='%(taggerdate:short) | %(tag) | %(contents)' refs/tags `

Comment: this doesn't work if your tags are formatted like this:  `1.1, 1.2...1.11, 1.12...1.20...etc`.  The date itself doesn't come into play when sorting, but the tag name itself.  You will get some order looking like this: `1.1, 1.11, 1.12, 1.2, 1.20`

Comment: @hellatan Thanks! I hadn’t even noticed that they were sorted by name.

Comment: np @JoshLee.  we were looking for a way to get the latest tag at work and i thought this might work but then ran into that problem.  ended up using this instead: `git describe --abbrev=0`

Comment: Or even a bit cleaner: `git for-each-ref --sort=taggerdate --format '%(tag)'`

Comment: I notice that taggerdate can be empty but creatordate always exists:  so I use: git for-each-ref --sort=creatordate --format '%(refname) %(creatordate) %(taggerdate)' refs/tags

Comment: `--sort=creatordate` works for both annotated and unannotated tags, but `--sort=taggerdate` only seems to work with annotated tags. tested using `git version 2.16.3`

Comment: how do I get the tags separated by pipe? tag1|tag2|tag3 and so on... ???

Comment: @austinheiman solution works for me. Using taggerdate continued to sort alphabetically but creatordate works perfectly

Comment: I ended up setting `tag.sort=creatordate` in my `~/.gitconfig`.  Now tags appear as I expect them to when using the git CLI.  That is, tag "1.0.2" appears immediately after "1.0.1", not with "1.0.10" between them, because that's not the order they were created.  (However, Atlassian's SourceTree still doesn't show them in the correct order. )

Comment: Any way to reverse sort by date?

Comment: Found it. To reverse the order and display with newest date on top, you can pipe to `tac` (`cat` backwards), like this: `git for-each-ref --sort=creatordate --format '%(refname) %(creatordate)' refs/tags | tac`. Source: [How can I reverse the order of lines in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742466/how-can-i-reverse-the-order-of-lines-in-a-file/742485#742485)

Comment: And [here is my own answer with an alternative form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69241512/4561887), including reversing the chronological list order of the tags.

Answer (score 97):

Git 2.8 (March 2016) documents another option [dating back to git 1.4.4 (Oct2006)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3175aa1ec28c8fb119058111a2f629425ef1aab0).
See [commit e914ef0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e914ef0d03d189611fe02e0fd26f5f964594767e) (05 Jan 2016) by [Eric Wong (`ele828`)](https://github.com/ele828).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 108cb77](https://github.com/git/git/commit/108cb77c868b541bb9bee43e9bfe9310827e1eb7), 20 Jan 2016)</sup>

See the new [`Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/108cb77c868b541bb9bee43e9bfe9310827e1eb7/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt#L145-L148)

> For commit and tag objects, the special `creatordate` and `creator`
> fields will correspond to the appropriate date or name-email-date tuple
> from the `committer` or `tagger` fields depending on the object type.
> **These are intended for working on a mix of annotated and lightweight tags**.

So using `creatordate` works with tags:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(*creatordate:raw)%(creatordate:raw) %(refname) %(*objectname) %(objectname)' refs/tags | \
sort -n | awk '{ print $4, $3; }'
```

Or:

```
git tag --sort=-creatordate
```

---

As I detail in "[How to sort git tags by version string order of form rc-X.Y.Z.W?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22634649/6309)",  you can add a sort order to [`git tag`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag) (since Git 2.0 June 2014).

That sort order includes as [field name (listed in `git for-each-ref`)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#_field_names) **taggerdate**. That allows for `git tag --sort=taggerdate` (mentioned by [DarVar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1086117/darvar) [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39396339/6309))
As an example, in the [`git/git` repo](https://github.com/git/git/) it will list the `v2.10.0` tag last:

```
v2.9.1
v2.9.2
v2.9.3
v2.10.0-rc0
v2.10.0-rc1
v2.10.0-rc2
v2.10.0
```

The default order would not (`git tag`):

```
v2.1.2
v2.1.3
v2.1.4
v2.10.0
v2.10.0-rc0
v2.10.0-rc1
v2.10.0-rc2
v2.2.0
```

---

With Git 2.44 (Q1 2024), [rc1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad1a6695454c6fd922617b03ebb5678841a17db5), "[`git branch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d4833b22abc0093153534cfaa93bb90be9a708ca/Documentation/git-branch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch))</sup> and friends learned to use the formatted text as sorting key, not the underlying timestamp value, when the `--sort` option is used with author or committer timestamp with a format specifier (e.g., "`--sort=creatordate:format:%H:%M:%S`").

See [commit 46176d7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/46176d77c9e0b219a78d64cb99d8dbf4d9bcde2d) (08 Feb 2024) by [Victoria Dye (`vdye`)](https://github.com/vdye).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d4833b2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d4833b22abc0093153534cfaa93bb90be9a708ca), 12 Feb 2024)</sup>

> ### [`ref-filter.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/46176d77c9e0b219a78d64cb99d8dbf4d9bcde2d): sort formatted dates by byte value
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Victoria Dye</sup>

> Update the ref sorting functions of '[`ref-filter.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/46176d77c9e0b219a78d64cb99d8dbf4d9bcde2d/ref-filter.c)' so that when date fields are specified with a format string (such as in '[`git for-each-ref --sort=creatordate:<something>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/46176d77c9e0b219a78d64cb99d8dbf4d9bcde2d/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref))</sup> ), they are sorted by their formatted string value rather than by the underlying numeric timestamp.
>
> Currently, date fields are always sorted by timestamp, regardless of whether formatting information is included in the '`--sort`' key.
>
> Leaving the default (unformatted) date sorting unchanged, sorting by the formatted date string adds some flexibility to '`for-each-ref`' by allowing for behavior like "sort by year, then by refname within each year" or "sort by time of day".
>
> Because the inclusion of a format string previously had no effect on sort behavior, this change likely will not affect existing usage of '`for-each-ref`' or other ref listing commands.

`git for-each-ref` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/46176d77c9e0b219a78d64cb99d8dbf4d9bcde2d/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt#L362-L366):

> As a special case for the date-type fields, you may specify a format for the date by adding `:` followed by date format name (see the values the `--date` option to [`git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) takes).
>
> If this formatting is provided in a `--sort` key, references will be sorted according to the byte-value of the formatted string rather than the numeric value of the underlying timestamp.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was wondering why some dates were empty. I was already suspecting lightweight tags. I'm glad I don't need to recreate the tags thanks to `creatordate`!

Answer (score 40):

```
git log --tags --simplify-by-decoration --pretty="format:%ci %d"
```

Also nice output from (without date field):

```
git log --tags --decorate --simplify-by-decoration --oneline
```

To see full history with dependencies and striped linear commits (only essential events, like tagging and branching/merging):

```
git log --graph --decorate --simplify-by-decoration --oneline --all
```

Comment: For lazy people: `git log --tags --simplify-by-decoration --pretty="format:%ci %d" | grep "tag:"` and it works best for me.

Comment: Note that this is ordered by the commit date, not the date the tags were created. The (currently) top rated answer from Josh Lee does order by the date the tag was created.

Answer (score 33):

This one-liner displays dates & tags:

```
git tag --format='%(creatordate:short)%09%(refname:strip=2)'
```

Output:

```
2015-09-27      v0.1.0
2019-10-22      v0.10.0
2020-07-08      v0.12.0
2015-11-18      v0.2.0
2020-12-08      v1.0.0
```

Tags are sorted in lexicographic order by default. If you prefer to sort by date:

```
git tag --format='%(creatordate:short)%09%(refname:strip=2)' --sort=creatordate
```

Output:

```
2015-09-27      v0.1.0
2015-11-18      v0.2.0
2019-10-22      v0.10.0
2020-07-08      v0.12.0
2020-12-08      v1.0.0
```

See [VonC answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34919313/776208) for more details.

Comment: Is this nice method bound to sort them by date? ascending? descending?

Answer (score 21):

```
git tag --sort=-taggerdate
```

According to the man page, "Prefix - to sort in descending order of the value. "

[`git tag`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag) uses the same sorting keys as [`git-for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#_field_names), which is where the keys are documented.

Comment: This is probably the most correct based on question. Here is the link to the docs outlining the possible sort fields: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref

Comment: This response doesn't take into account lightweight tags as they have empty "taggerdate". Other responses with "creatordate" are more accurate.

Comment: `git --no-pager tag --sort=-creatordate`
seems to be more what I needed

Answer (score 12):

To have annotated tags and lightweight tags sorted altogether, based on the commit date, I'm using:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(*committerdate:raw)%(committerdate:raw) %(refname) %(*objectname) %(objectname)' refs/tags | \
  sort -n | awk '{ print $4, $3; }'
```

This command will list every tag and the associated commit object id, in chronological order.

Comment: Obfuscated a bit. ... In annotated tags, 'committerdate' is empty whereas in lightweight tags 'taggerdate' is empty. So as a workaround '*committerdate' is telling Git to backreference dates from the original commit object when it's lightweight. ...

Comment: Using 'creatordate' instead should effectively do the same thing.

Answer (score 9):

With Git `version 2.10.0.windows.1`

`git tag --sort=taggerdate`

Answer (score 7):

The following relies on the commit, so it doesn't matter if it has date information with the commit:

```
git log --tags --decorate --simplify-by-decoration|grep ^commit|grep tag|sed -e 's/^.*: //' -e 's/)$//' -e 's/,.*$//'|tac
```

The answer above by Josh Lee, relies on a tag date to get the order correct.

Comment: Not sure what the trailing command `tac` is - might change it to `more`. Anyway your command worked great - thanks!

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114041/how-can-i-get-the-tac-command-on-os-x

Comment: works great as longs as there only exists max. 1 tag per commit

Answer (score 6):

*<sub>Note: my `git --version` is `git version 2.25.1`.</sub>*

Note that for all commands below, if your tags are *annotated tags*, meaning you gave them a message, then use `--sort=taggerdate`. If your tags are *not* annotated with an attached messsage, however, then they are considered "lightweight tags", so use `--sort=creatordate` instead. See here: [why sort by taggerdate does not really work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70973008/4561887):

> Only *annotated tags* have their own separate tagger date.  As long as the tag is for a commit, both annotated tags and lightweight tags will have a "creator date", but only the annotated tags will have a separate "tagger date" here.  Displaying both values helps sort this out

Read more about "Annotated Tags" and "Lightweight Tags" here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging.

---

For a list `-l` of all tags, with up to 99 lines in the message field per tag (`-n99`), in chronological order with the newest tag *last*, do:

```bash
git tag -l -n99 --sort=taggerdate   # for annotated tags
git tag -l -n99 --sort=creatordate  # for lightweight tags
```

(My preferred form) to reverse the chronological order and put the newest tag *first*, add a minus sign (`-`) in front of `taggerdate`, like this:

```bash
git tag -l -n99 --sort=-taggerdate  # for annotated tags
git tag -l -n99 --sort=-creatordate # for lightweight tags
```

Going further:

To also search within the tags and only show tags which contain string `my string` somewhere in their name, add `'*my string*'` to the end. Note that the asterisks (`*`) are wild-cards in the search pattern:

```bash
git tag -l -n99 --sort=-taggerdate '*my string*'  # for annotated tags
git tag -l -n99 --sort=-creatordate '*my string*' # for lightweight tags
```

To only show the tag names, and NOT up to 99 lines of their tag messages, simply remove the `-n99` part:

```bash
git tag -l --sort=-taggerdate '*my string*'  # for annotated tags
git tag -l --sort=-creatordate '*my string*' # for lightweight tags
```

### Related

1. My answer on how to [show all tags in git log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69275540/4561887)

Answer (score 3):

Building on the earlier mentioned methods, I wanted to also see the actual tag date on the list, and so my in-use version is:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(*creatordate:raw)%(creatordate:raw) %(creatordate:short) %(refname) %(*objectname) %(objectname)' refs/tags | sort -n | awk '{ print $3, $5, $4 }'
```