# git tags and time

Tags: git, commit, git-tag

I was under the impression that a tag would act like a commit in that if I have a clone based on an old commit, I wouldn't expect to see new tags listed in the git tag output.

However, this assumption is evidently wrong.  It kinds wrecks the way I was planning to use tags.  I am using simple tags.  Would some other type of tag work differently as far as time goes?

Comment: To get the most helpful answers, please be as specific as possible about your goals. For example, describe your workflow when using tags. Also, explain what a "simple tag" is and how you expect it to behave. If your background is in with a different vcs (e.g. subversion) please state that too. Are you expecting a tag to be part of the history, such that if you view the repo at an earlier point in history, you won't see the tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure of your goal, but git doesn't make it easy to sort the tags by the date of the commits pointed to.

After some research and effort I came up with this:

```
git tag | xargs -I@ git log --format=format:"%ci %h @%n" -1 @ | sort
```

Sample output:

```
2008-10-30 08:51:04 -0700 221793e REL_1.0.0
2008-10-31 12:06:57 -0700 51a406c REL_1.0.1
2008-10-31 13:01:18 -0700 e1e9751 REL_1.0.2
```

With a little tweaking, this can also works with "git branch" to handle the asterisk indicating the current branch.

Another command that may be helpful...
Include the ref names (branch, tags, etc) in the log output:

```
git log --decorate
```

Do you have a workflow or script that relies on the assumption that newer tags don't exist in old clones?
If you're cloning a local repo, you could try "git clone --no-hardlinks". But it may not be the best solution for your goals.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269927/how-can-i-list-all-tags-in-my-git-repository-by-the-date-they-were-created

Comment: @jleedev thanks for the info. You can even force iso8601 for timestamps. However, my brief viewing of the man page doesn't seem to show an easy way to get the commit-date of the target of the tag without using a long script.

Answer (score 1):

A `git tag` under normal circumstances is fixed.  If you reference it yesterday and reference it today, it will point to the same SHA/tree/checkout.

However, as time progresses and you change your repository (either locally or due to `git-fetch` et al) the same SHA may have more ways to describe (`git describe`) that same commit.  Multiple tags may point to the same SHA (or nearby commits if no commit points directly to the SHA) and which one `git describe` returns may change.

Perhaps you can describe what you are trying to do and people can see if there is are any ideas.