# Get the time and date of git tags

Tags: git, date, time, git-tag

I have a project that is using git and have tagged all the releases with a tag.

```
$ git tag
v1.0.0
v1.0.1
v1.0.2
v1.0.3
v1.1.0
```

My goal is to list the releases and release dates in a web interface (tag/commit date = release date). Currently we list all the releases by using `git tag`.

**How can I get the time and date for when the tag was made (or the commit it points to)?**

Comment: It's good to precise here that it's the commit date of the tag that you're after. As a tag has no date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I list all tags in my Git repository by the date they were created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269927/how-can-i-list-all-tags-in-my-git-repository-by-the-date-they-were-created)

Comment: @jobwat [Annotated tags **do** have a date](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging#_annotated_tags).

Comment: TL;DR if you want a *tag* date, and not underlying _commit_ date, **you can't use `git log`**, but **must use `git-for-each-ref`**. In my case I wanted relative time (`%ar` from git log); I managed to have it with: `git for-each-ref --format="%(creatordate:relative)" refs/tags/MYTAG`

Comment: Just adding, if you want an actual date for the *tag* date, as mentioned in @jakub.g 's comment, you can do the following: `git for-each-ref --format="%(creatordate)" refs/tags/MYTAG`, removing the `:relative`.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Use the `--format` argument to `git log`:

```
git log -1 --format=%ai MY_TAG_NAME
```

Comment: TIP - Replace "TAG" with the tag name. For example, `git log -1 --format=%ai v0.2.3`.

Comment: If you want ISO8601, do `--format=%aI` (capital "I")

Comment: `git log -1 --format=%ai MY_TAG_NAME | cat` disable page view

Comment: What's "-1" doing?

Comment: @Blademaster It tells `git log` to show only one commit, the one pertaining to the tag. The default behavior is to show all commits from the specified one back to the first commit in the reposotory.

Comment: This answer prints the author date of the tagged commit, not the date the tag was created.

Comment: The *tag* date can be gotten with `git for-each-ref --format="%(creatordate)" refs/tags/MYTAG` (replace `MYTAG` with your own tag).

Answer (score 137):

This always worked for me:

```
git log --tags --simplify-by-decoration --pretty="format:%ci %d"
```

Consult the "PRETTY FORMATS" section of the git-log manpage for details of the format string if you want a different date formatting.

Comment: To be warned though, this will list the date/time for commit, but not the date/time for the annotated tag.

Comment: Just put `taglog = log --tags --simplify-by-decoration --pretty='format:%ci %d'` (note the single-, NOT double-quotes) in the [alias] section of your .gitconfig file, and now you've got a git taglog command :)

Answer (score 79):

One more option:

```sh
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short) | %(creatordate)" "refs/tags/*"
```

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#_field_names for format options

`%(creatordate)` gives the date of the commit pointed to, to see the date the tag was created on use `%(taggerdate)`

You can incorporate the shell directly:

```sh
$> git for-each-ref --shell --format="ref=%(refname:short) dt=%(taggerdate:format:%s)" "refs/tags/*"

ref='v1.10' dt='1483807817'
ref='v1.11' dt='1483905854'
ref='v1.12.0' dt='1483974797'
ref='v1.12.1' dt='1484015966'
ref='v1.13' dt='1484766542'
ref='v1.2' dt='1483414377'
ref='v1.3' dt='1483415058'
ref='v1.3-release' dt='' <-- not an annotated tag, just a pointer to a commit so no 'taggerdate', it would have a 'creator date'.
ref='v1.3.1' dt='1483487085'
ref='v1.4' dt='1483730146'
ref='v1.9' dt='1483802985'
```

Comment: This is  the best answer for getting the tag date.

Comment: Alternatively, you can get the unix timestamp with `git for-each-ref --format="%(taggerdate:unix)" refs/tags` or as substring in `git for-each-ref --format="%(taggerdate:raw)" refs/tags`

Comment: Thank you!  All of the other answers just give the commit date and not the tag date.

Comment: Yes defo best answer as it only shows the actual tags, not all commits, shame crappy SO has other answers rated higher.

Comment: same result with less typing: `git tag --format "%(refname:short) %(creatordate:short)"`

Comment: Are there docs for the `git tag --format` options? (edit) `git tag --help`:  `--format=<format>  
           A string that interpolates %(fieldname) from a tag ref being shown and the object it points at. The format is the same as that of git-for-each-
           ref(1). When unspecified, defaults to %(refname:strip=2).` 
So, `git for-each-ref --help` lists the format options and field names.

Comment: `%(creatordate) gives the date of the commit pointed to` not for me though, e.g. I have a tag for which `git show` says the date of the tag is Jul 17, and the commit which was tagged was created on Jul 5 and comitted on Jul 14. Yet both `creatordate` and `taggerdate` say Jul 17

Comment: If your tags have `/` in then it won't match them. Should use "refs/tags/**" to match EVERY tag

Answer (score 30):

Note that both of the above solutions get you the commit date, which can be wildly different than when that commit was tagged for release. To get the date of the tag itself, you've got to find the tag itself with `rev-parse`, read it with `cat-file`, and then parse it. A little pipeline:

`git rev-parse v1.0.0 | xargs git cat-file -p | egrep '^tagger' | cut -f2 -d '>'`

Comment: Good, only problem is the result is not formatted (1419372909 -0300)

Comment: Once you have the commit id from rev-parse, I believe you can do: git rev-parse v1.0.0 | xargs git show -s --pretty=%aI

Comment: @Keith Now you're back to showing the author date of the commit instead of the tagged date, at least for annotated tags

Answer (score 3):

There is no simple option in git tag command to do this. I found most convenient to run

```
git log --decorate=full
```

to list all commits including tags if there are some. For listing only commits that are tagged use

```
git log --decorate=full --simplify-by-decoration
```

For details use

```
git help log
```

Answer (score 2):

one can use `gawk` (not `awk`) to convert date in the "tagger" line to something human-readable:

```
git rev-parse v4.4-rc1 | xargs git cat-file -p | gawk '/^tagger/ { print strftime(PROCINFO["strftime"], $(NF-1)) }'
```

if one does not like `gawk` then `date` can be used to convert unix time:

```
git rev-parse v2.76 | xargs git cat-file -p | awk '/^tagger/ { print "@" $(NF-1) }' | xargs date -d
```

and example (`dnsmasq` git repo):

```
$ git rev-parse v2.76 | xargs git cat-file -p | awk '/^tagger/ { print "@" $(NF-1) }' | xargs date -d
Wed May 18 16:52:12 CEST 2016
```

Comment: do you try this from yourside??

Comment: surely. it works, `dnsmasq` git repo, for example:

`$ git rev-parse v2.76 | xargs git cat-file -p | awk '/^tagger/ { print strftime(PROCINFO["strftime"], $(NF-1)) }'`
`Wed May 18 16:52:12 CEST 2016`

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers here are great and in the proper git style. But I needed a tag, its date and its message and only the last 10 tags. So I just did it in a very pedestrian way. But save it as a shell function or script and it becomes a one-liner.

```
for ver in `git tag | tail -10`; do
    DATE=`git log -1 --format=%ai $ver | awk '{print $1}'`
    MESSAGE=`git tag -n $ver | cat | awk '{a=match($0, $2); print substr($0,a)}'`
    echo "$ver \t| $DATE | $MESSAGE"
done
```