# github tag created and pushed at different time, what will the time be on github tag detial

Tags: github, tags

If I tag the commit and forgot to push it. When I push it 3 days after, what will the time be when git show [that tag]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date/tome associated to that tag will be the creation date, not the date when you (finally) push it.

You can see it with ([as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42191640/6309)):

```
git tag --format "%(refname:short) %(creatordate:short)"
```