# List all annotated tags, with annotation, sorted by commit date

Tags: git, git-log, git-tag

It seems easy to list all tags with annotations, with e.g.:

```
git tag -n99
```

or

```
git for-each-ref --format '%(refname:short) %(contents)' refs/tags
```

And it's also possible to use `git log` to list tags by creator date, e.g. ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208734/get-the-time-and-date-of-git-tags)):

```
git log --tags --simplify-by-decoration --pretty="format:%cs %d"
```

However, **neither of these answer the question**, because as far as I can tell:

- **it is not possible to sort annotated tags by commit date** with `git tag`, because the tags point to a tag annotation object, and so `committerdate` is empty. You can confirm this with `git tag --format='%(committerdate)'`

  - There is a `creatordate`, which lists the commit date for **un-annotated** commits, and the tag creation date for annotated commits, which is also useless for this question.
- **it is not possible to show the tag annotations with `git log`**, because there is no tag annotation option in the formatter (and this wouldn't make sense anyway, because a single commit can have multiple tags.

So, is there a way to do this that lists all tags, sorted by commit date, and showing both commit date and annotations? I don't care about unannotated tags for this question.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is in the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt---formatltformatgt)

> If fieldname is prefixed with an asterisk (*) and the ref points at a
> tag object, use the value for the field in the object which the tag
> object refers to (instead of the field in the tag object).

To show the committerdate, use `%(*committerdate)`. For example,

```
git for-each-ref refs/tags --format="%(*committerdate:iso) %(contents:subject) %(refname:short)" --sort=*committerdate
```

To reverse the result, use `--sort=-*committerdate` instead. It's also easy to use `sort` or `sort -r`.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I saw that asterix in one example, but trying it didn't work. Should have known to look up it's meaning.