# Git: How to sort tags by the date of the corresponding commit?

Tags: git, sorting

Lightweight tags can be sorted by the date of the corresponding commit using (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36636526/2828064))

```
git tag --sort=authordate
```

Annotated tags can be sorted by the date of the corresponding commit using (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71671255/2828064))

```
git tag --sort=*authordate
```

It is possible to specify several sort fields:

```
git tag --sort=authordate --sort=*authordate --format='[%(*authordate:iso)][%(authordate:iso)] %(refname:short)'
```

but that groups all lightweight tags together and all annotated tags together because `*authordate` is empty for lightweight tags and `authordate` is empty for annotated tags. So I guess I would need the possibility to specify a fallback field which is used instead of another field if the other field is empty. Does git have a feature like that? (I haven't found it in `git tag --help`.)

How do I sort all tags (a mix of annotated tags and lightweight tags) by the authordate of the corresponding commit?

Comment: There is a `creatordate` - does that help?

Comment: @naught101 yes, there is a creatordate but no, it uses the date of the tag not of the corresponding commit in case of an annotated tag. And it uses the committer date not the author date in case of a lightweight tag (although I concede that I meant to ask for the committer date...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quickest way to get this done cleanly is probably

```
git tag --format='%(objectname)^{}' \
| git cat-file --batch-check \
| awk '$2=="commit" { print $1 }' \
| git log --stdin --author-date-order --no-walk --decorate --oneline
```

because tags don't have to point at commits, you can tag anything. `*authordate` of a tag pointing to a tag will also be blank despite it (usually) eventually resolving to a commit.

See [`git help revisions`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgtemegemv0998em) for the `^{}` revision-expression syntax.

Comment: thank you for your answer and pointing out that `*authordate` can be empty for annotated tags, too. I wasn't aware of that. I have added an explanation how the command works and an extended version of your command with a `git tag` like output format (tag names only, one line per tag).

Comment: why has my edit been rejected? was the explanation wrong?

Comment: It was unfocused, and not every answer needs to be an ELI5.