# How to list the last occurance of a specific string in Terminal

Tags: git, sorting, awk, filter, grep

I have managed to list the git tags with the help of the following command:

```
git for-each-ref refs/tags --sort=-taggerdate --format='%(refname)'
```

as described in [How can I list all tags in my Git repository by the date they were created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269927/how-can-i-list-all-tags-in-my-git-repository-by-the-date-they-were-created).
The result looks as follows:

```
4.18.038
4.18.039
4.18.040
4.18.041
4.18.042
4.18.043
4.18.044
4.19.001
4.19.002
4.19.003
4.19.004
4.19.005
4.19.006
4.19.007
4.19.008
4.19.009
4.19.010
4.19.011
4.19.012
4.19.013
4.19.014
4.19.015
4.19.016
4.19.017
4.19.018
4.19.019
4.20.000
```

I would like to select only the last occurrence(latest) of each version.
Eg.

```
4.18.044
4.19.019
4.20.000
```

Any ideas how I could achieve that?

PS. I am using Windows 7 with MINGW32

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F. '{a[$1,$2]=$0} END{for (i in a) print a[i]}' test
4.18.044
4.19.019
4.20.000
```

- `-F.` sets the field seperator as `.`
- `'a[$1,$2]=$0` assigns the value of entire record to an array `a` indexed by the first 2 columns, `$1`, `$2`
- `for (i in a) print a[i]` prints the content of the array

**Caution**

This works only if the file is sorted. If not you can use `sort` and pipe the result to `awk`

```
$ sort test | awk -F. '{a[$1$2]=$0} END{for (i in a) print a[i]}' 
4.18.044
4.19.019
4.20.000
```

Comment: this is fine... as long as the list is already sorted, of course. If not, you can use `sort -V` first, as sputnick mentioned in his answer.

Comment: @fedorqui Good point !! I have edited my answer to include that as well. Thank you:)

Comment: git for-each-ref refs/tags --sort=-taggerdate --format='%(refname)' | sort | awk -F. '{a[$1$2]=$0} END{for (i in a) print a[i]}' worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Never use an array index like `a[$1$2]`, use `a[$1,$2]` instead. Consider the difference in behavior of each if the input contained the lines `a bc` and `ab c`.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do using `sort` to ensure that the version list is well sorted :

```
sort -V file | awk -F '.' '{arr[$2]=$0}END{for (a in arr) {print arr[a]}}'
4.18.044
4.19.019
4.20.000
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sort only:

```
~$ sort -r f | sort -t. -k1,2 -u
4.18.044
4.19.019
4.20.000
```

the `-t` specifies the delimiter, the `-k1,2` the fields and `-u` prints only 1 of them

Answer (score 1):

```
tac file | awk -F'.' '!seen[$1,$2]++' | tac
```