# How can I get the oldest tag in my git project?

Tags: git, github

I want to get the oldest tag in my tag Project. How do I get hold of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269927/how-can-i-list-all-tags-in-my-git-repository-by-the-date-they-were-created

Answer (score 1):

For only the oldest (not the whole sorted list) you could output it with

```
git for-each-ref --sort=creatordate --count=1 refs/tags
```

then if you need a specific format, check the [--format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt---formatltformatgt) option.