# why sort by taggerdate does not really work?

Tags: git

```
$ git tag -l --sort=taggerdate --format='%(creatordate:short)%09%(refname:strip=2)'
2021-08-11      v0.4.2
2022-02-02      v0.7.0c
2021-08-10      v0.4.0
2021-08-10      v0.4.1
2021-09-15      v0.5.0
2021-11-04      vfix-12
2021-11-17      vfix-23
```

this also affected the `git describe` result, it is using the vfix-23 instead of v0.7.0c. Is this expected or this is some kind of bug?

**update**

according to @torek I should show the taggerdate instead:

```
$ git tag -l --sort=taggerdate --format='%(taggerdate:short)%09%(creatordate:short)%09%(refname:strip=2)'
        2021-08-11      v0.4.2
        2022-02-02      v0.7.0c
2021-08-10      2021-08-10      v0.4.0
2021-08-10      2021-08-10      v0.4.1
2021-09-15      2021-09-15      v0.5.0
2021-11-04      2021-11-04      vfix-12
2021-11-17      2021-11-17      vfix-23
```

We can see there is not taggerdate for v0.7.0c

Comment: The "tagger date" and the "creator date" may be different, and *are* different if the tag is an annotated tag. In this case the creatordate is the *commit* date and the taggerdate is the *tag* date. (It's possible for those two to match, but it's very unlikely: someone would have to force the time stamps to match, or tag the commit at the same second as they made the commit. The latter can happen with machine-generated commit-and-tag though.)

Comment: @torek you are correct, the non-annotated tag does not have taggerdate. If you can format it into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

Only *annotated tags* have their own separate tagger date.  As long as the tag is for a commit, both annotated tags and lightweight tags will have a "creator date", but only the annotated tags will have a separate "tagger date" here.  Displaying both values helps sort this out; note that there's also the `*` format prefix to indirect from an annotated tag to the commit, so as to get consistent handling.

The `git describe` problem is occurring in this case for a different reason: by default, `git describe` *ignores* lightweight tags entirely.  The idea here is that *annotated* tags are "more real" in some sense; you're supposed to use annotated tags for anything serious.  Here's what [the `git tag` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag) says about this:

> Annotated tags are meant for release while lightweight tags are meant
> for private or temporary object labels. For this reason, some git
> commands for naming objects (like `git describe`) will ignore lightweight
> tags by default.

## Long

For Git tags, there are effectively two "kinds" of tags, which Git calls *lightweight* and *annotated*.  It's a good idea to learn about the underlying implementation here because Git's abstractions [leak a lot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction).  In this particular case, the date-stamp details leak out.  So, here are the details:

- A *ref* is a name, generally starting with `refs/`, that contains a Git hash ID or *Object ID*, aka *OID*.  Git has four internal object types—commits, annotated tags, trees, and blobs—and each object gets an OID.  The OIDs you see the most (because you may have to cut-and-paste them for instance) are those for commit objects; we rarely view tag OIDs, and even less rarely view tree or blob OIDs, but they all exist and *some* refs can store any kind of OID.

  Note that each name holds exactly one OID.
- *Branch* names start with `refs/heads/`, so `master` is really `refs/heads/master`, `main` is really `refs/heads/main`, `feature/tall` is really `refs/heads/feature/tall`, and so on.  Branch names are limited: they can only hold *commit* OIDs.  They have some extra features: you can get "on a branch", and when you do, that's the commit you have checked out right now, and when you make a *new* commit, Git automatically stores the *new* commit's hash ID into the branch name.  (This has nothing to do with the tags, but is worth knowing.)
- *Tag* names start with `refs/tags/`.  Unlike branch names, a tag name can hold any kind of OID.  It's normal, though, to store either a *commit OID* or an *annotated tag OID* into a tag name.

The internals of a commit object are somewhat relevant here, so let's look at the top section (up to the first blank line) of an example commit:

```
$ git cat-file -p 22d2f70e85e767abba2e284e32c0edb7f749e29c | sed -e 's/@/ /' -e '/^$/q'
tree 84d6d269a557b1e109af0a0ff3706e29756bd490
parent f2b255141b3008a46b4946e7da44b966797e4355
author Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason <avarab gmail.com> 1641919223 +0100
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1642109949 -0800
```

We'll ignore the `tree` and `parent` lines and concentrate on the `author` and `committer` lines here.  These contain three parts each, besides the keyword at the front:

- There's a user name (text string) that appears before the opening angle bracket.  This is the name of the author or committer.  It's an arbitrary byte sequence (except for the fact that it may not contain newlines or angle brackets) that is chosen by the person making the commit, so it cannot really be trusted on its own.
- Then there is an opening angle bracket, an email address, and a closing angle bracket.  The email address is a similar user-specified string that cannot really be trusted on its own.  People don't normally put egregious lies in these fields, but you must remember that they are essentially uncontrolled by Git itself.
- Finally, there are Git-generated fields consisting of two strings of digits, with the last one being signed.  These are the author date (for the author line) and committer date (for the committer line).

The timestamps are Unix-style time stamps (seconds since 1970, leap second handling unspecified) along with the time zone offset in hours and minutes: negative offsets, like `-0800`, represent west-of-GMT values such as Pacific Standard Time (-8 hours) and positive offsets like `+0100` represent east-of-GMT values (e.g., Norway, on Central European time at GMT+1).

Now let's look at a *tag object*, in this case the annotated tag object for Git version 2.35.1:

```
$ git cat-file -p v2.35.1 | sed 's/@/ /'
object 4c53a8c20f8984adb226293a3ffd7b88c3f4ac1a
type commit
tag v2.35.1
tagger Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1643417339 -0800

Git 2.35.1
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
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=/DjY
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

Here, we see that this annotated tag:

- carries an OID (for commit `4c53a8c20f8984adb226293a3ffd7b88c3f4ac1a` in this case: that's the commit that *is* Git 2.35.1);
- carries a `type` field, which is the type of the target object;
- carries a `tag` field, which contains the tag's name, which should match the name we just used to find it, if we used a tag name to find it; and
- carries a `tagger`, which looks a great deal like an `author` or `committer` in a commit object.

In particular the tagger line has the same three fields: name, email address, and timestamp-with-time-zone.

This particular annotated tag also carries a *PGP signature* (see [digital signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) and [Pretty Good Privacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy)).  The signature provides a testable assertion that Junio Hamano did in fact sign off on this particular tag, representing that this tag for this commit is really his work, and not some counterfeit.  That, in turn, verifies—to whatever extent you trust PGP and the Merkle chains in Git<sup>1</sup>—the *tagged commit and all of its history*.  So the presence of this PGP-signed annotated tag gives you at least some assurance that the author and committer text strings can be trusted.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that current Git [Merkle trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree) use SHA-1, which is a bit dodgy given current computing abilities.  However, they place limitations *on* the SHA-1 usage, which firms it up a bit.  Still, SHA-2 would help here.

---

#### Now we can really define annotated tags properly

Now that you know what a *tag object* is, looks like, and does for you, we can really see the difference between a *lightweight tag* and an *annotated tag*.  A tag *name*, like `refs/heads/v2.35.1` in the Git repository for Git, contains a hash ID:

```
$ git rev-parse v2.35.1
73807ff71e1acef4cfa35fe5cfb16d5878b6cd12
$ git cat-file -t 73807ff71e1acef4cfa35fe5cfb16d5878b6cd12
tag
```

This is the tag object we printed out earlier.  That tag object contains a commit hash ID, and that commit hash ID is the tagged *commit*.  So this is an *annotated tag* for Git v2.35.1.  There are two special syntax constructs for `git rev-parse` to make it follow the tag:<sup>2</sup>

```
$ git rev-parse v2.35.1^{}
4c53a8c20f8984adb226293a3ffd7b88c3f4ac1a
$ git rev-parse v2.35.1^{commit}
4c53a8c20f8984adb226293a3ffd7b88c3f4ac1a
```

and that (`4c53a8c...`) is the value we saw earlier.

If we make a *lightweight tag* now, point it to the same commit, and use `git rev-parse` on it, we'll get the *commit* hash ID, not that of an annotated tag:

```
$ git tag tmp v2.35.1^{}
$ git rev-parse tmp
4c53a8c20f8984adb226293a3ffd7b88c3f4ac1a
```

This is a *lightweight* tag because it points directly to the commit.  Deleting that tag and creating a tag with a message makes a new *annotated* tag object:

```
$ git tag -d tmp
Deleted tag 'tmp' (was 4c53a8c20f)
$ git tag -m message tmp v2.35.1^{}
$ git rev-parse tmp
2b92bdd78a61718279a75ce722b14979efcc40a4
$ git cat-file -p tmp | sed 's/@/ /'
object 4c53a8c20f8984adb226293a3ffd7b88c3f4ac1a
type commit
tag tmp
tagger Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com> 1643936151 -0800

message
```

So it's the annotations—whether made with `-a` or `-m` or `-s` or `-u`—that carry the extra data, including the tagger date and optional PGP, GPG, or other digital signature.<sup>3</sup>  To get these, you must create an *annotated* tag.  Only then will `git describe` use it by default.

---

<sup>2</sup>The `^{}` suffix means *find the non-tag object*, while the `^{commit}` suffix means *find the non-tag object **and make sure it is a commit object***.  Since a tag object can point to any of the four kinds of object, a tag object does not necessarily point to a commit.  It could point to a tree or blob object, for instance—or it can even point to another tag object!  If it does point to another tag object, Git will follow *that* tag to *its* target, and will repeat this following process until it arrives at some non-tag object.  Git calls this process "peeling the tag", using the idea that tag objects are like layers in onions, except that there should be something more than just an odor remaining once you've peeled off all the layers.

<sup>3</sup>Git is growing support for ssh-key-based signing.  It's still not quite ready for most users, I think, but it's getting there.