# How to find out in which tag a file change is included

Tags: git

I want to find out which files changed in what tag. So I use `git whatchanged` but this prints me the commit IDs. I want to print the commits in a format like in `git describe` (which takes the last tag and adds the number of additional commits.

The commands

```
git whatchanged --pretty=%d *
git whatchanged --pretty=%gd *
```

are both not working (no output of the commit info at all).

EDIT:

I am using the command on a list of files (by using the `*`), i.e. what happens if the tagging took place after that commit. Aim is to find out the software version which contains the commit

Answer (score 2):

Based on VonC's answer I ended up in using

```
FILEPATH=/the/path/I/want/to/Observe
git log --name-only --oneline --tags --pretty="%d"|egrep "$FILEPATH|^ \("
```

Explanation:

`git log` shows the changes of the full repository including the tags. Then I grep for the files I am interested in. Additionally I grep for `␣(` at the beginning of a line to get the tag names which look for example like `␣(1.1.0)`

Comment: Great, that seems more precise than my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to use `whatchanged` from quite some time now: see "[Difference between `git-log` and `git-whatchanged`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18585297/6309)".

Instead, use [`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

```
git log -p --no-walk --tags --pretty="%H %d" --decorate=full
```

That works correctly since git 1.8.5.4 (see "[show all tags in git log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21078958/6309)")

With the `-p` option, it display the diffs.

Other options are available for displaying files:

```
 git log --name-only --oneline --tags --pretty="%d" | grep -v "^$" | more
```

(See more at "[How to show changed file name only with `git log`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14207414/6309)")

For instance, on the git repo itself:

```
C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\git>
git log --name-only --oneline --tags --pretty="%d"|grep -v "^$"|more

 (tag: v2.0.0-rc0)
Documentation/RelNotes/2.0.0.txt
GIT-VERSION-GEN
Documentation/RelNotes/2.0.0.txt
config.c
contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh
contrib/remote-helpers/test-bzr.sh
t/t5560-http-backend-noserver.sh
t/t7001-mv.sh
contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh
contrib/remote-helpers/git-remote-bzr
contrib/remote-helpers/test-bzr.sh
contrib/remote-helpers/git-remote-bzr
contrib/remote-helpers/git-remote-hg
contrib/remote-helpers/test-hg-bidi.sh
contrib/remote-helpers/test-hg-hg-git.sh

 (tag: v1.9.2, upstream/maint)
Documentation/RelNotes/1.9.2.txt
Documentation/git.txt
GIT-VERSION-GEN
Documentation/git-http-backend.txt
utf8.c
Documentation/RelNotes/2.0.0.txt
Documentation/RelNotes/1.9.2.txt
git-p4.py
contrib/hooks/multimail/CHANGES
contrib/hooks/multimail/README
contrib/hooks/multimail/README.Git
contrib/hooks/multimail/git_multimail.py
contrib/hooks/multimail/post-receive
builtin/pack-objects.c
....
```

Comment: How can I see the list of changed files in `git log`?

Comment: This shows the diffs - what about only the changed filenames?

Comment: I also edited the question - that might make it more complicated.