# Git log: Show commits by specific author + tags by all authors

Tags: git

We use git tags to mark our releases.

I'm currently using `git log --author="Steve"` to get all commits by a certain author. In addition to that I would like to see which of these commits belong to which release. For that reason, I want to display all the tags aswell (ideally inbetween the commits)
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try including `--decorate`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [show all tags in git log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211604/show-all-tags-in-git-log)

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you meant to ask is: How can I show:

- all commits by Steve, plus
- any tagged commit along with its tag

This is difficult because `--author=Steve` constrains `git log` to show only those commits whose author is Steve, no matter which commits are encountered in the revision walk.  The `--decorate` that [Adam suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70739444/git-log-show-commits-by-specific-author-tags-by-all-authors#comment125055346_70739444) won't help: the tagged commits—those that would come out decorated with the tags you would like to see—are **omitted** if they're not *authored by Steve*.

What you would need to do is:

- enumerate all commits authored by Steve (saving their hash IDs somewhere for instance), then
- enumerate all commits that are tagged (saving *their* hash IDs as well), then
- run `git log --no-walk --stdin` on this list of hash IDs.

But I believe your overall strategy is flawed here:

> In addition to that I would like to see which of these commits belong to which release ...

The `git log` command necessarily "linearizes" its output.  That is, suppose we have the following branch-and-merge-y structure, with newer commits towards the right and older ones towards the left:

```
          o--●--o--o   <-- tag: v1.X
         /          \
...--o--o            o--●--o--o   <-- some-branch, tag: vZ.0
         \          /
          o--●--o--o   <-- tag: vY.1
```

where the solid bullet `●` represents a "Steve commit".  There are three such commits and they will be emitted in some random-looking order, with the constraint that the rightmost one will come out before the top and bottom ones.  The output is *one commit at a time*, but the top and bottom bulleted commits are literally *parallel*.

If we add the tagged commits to the output, we'll see version Z, then the rightmost Steve commit.  Then we'll see versions 1.X and Y.1 in some order, and the remaining two Steve commits in some order, but *the order won't be predictable* and the version tags may *both* come out *before* the two interesting Steve commits come out.  We'd then infer that both Steve commits are in version 1.X, or both are on version Y.1, when in fact they are in two different releases.

If we can control the graph-walk order, we can do better.  While `git log` *can* do this to some extent with `--topo-order`, I believe a sufficiently complicated graph will defeat this as well.

Hence, to correctly identify the tag that "contains" or "describes" a particular Steve commit, we should instead:

1. Enumerate all Steve commits.  Place the list of hash IDs in an input somewhere (e.g., a temporary file).  (Use `git rev-list --author=Steve HEAD` or similar; choose your starting point(s) appropriately.)
2. Use `git log --no-walk` to show each such commit, but also use `git describe --contains` to *describe* each commit *relative to the best tag Git can find*.

Since *you* can easily control the enumeration of the hash IDs saved in the temporary file, you can simply run each of these two commands (`git log --no-walk $hash` and `git describe [options] $hash`) in the desired order, on each commit, one at a time.  You now know which tag describes (optionally and likely desired, "contains") each Steve commit.