# How to get list of branch heads in Git?

Tags: git

I am trying to get a list of branch heads in Git. So far I have found `git log --simplify-by-decoration` which seems to include all branches and show the heads, but it also shows one extra commit which is useless for me. Is there an even better way to do this or is that what I should use?

So to make it clear: I want to have an output that gives me the head of all branches in my local repository. Basically, I just need the hash of each of the heads, but I can just regex it from whatever output I get.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should be able to use the `git show-ref` command. [git-show-ref documentation](https://schacon.github.io/git/git-show-ref.html)

```
git show-ref --heads -s
```

Comment: You can also use `git show-ref --heads -s`, which will only show the hash without the ref name. No need to pipe and cut

Comment: what's the diff between this `git show-ref --heads -s` and `git log`? I thought they would both show the same list of SHAs but they don't

Comment: `git log` shows the commit history from the current branch, this command shows the HEAD SHA for all local branches. They are very different things.

Comment: I personally prefer `git branch -v --all`.

Comment: `git show-ref --heads -s` gives HEAD SHA only. I need other details as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you do use `git show-ref --heads -s` on a large repository, one with other references than branches or tags (like a [gerrit repository](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/concept-refs-for-namespace.html)) make sure to use Git 2.37 (Q3 2022).

"[`git show-ref --heads`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2246937e4165d4a7a238f1ea52da36bc7aa1274a/Documentation/git-show-ref.txt#L40)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-ref#Documentation/git-show-ref.txt---heads))</sup> (and "`--tags`") still iterated over *all* the refs only to discard refs outside the specified area, which has been corrected with Git 2.37 (Q3 2022).

See [commit c0c9d35](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0c9d35e27e777d117362f6e96f433eb2b55bf76) (03 Jun 2022) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2246937](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2246937e4165d4a7a238f1ea52da36bc7aa1274a), 13 Jun 2022)</sup>

> ### [`builtin/show-ref.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0c9d35e27e777d117362f6e96f433eb2b55bf76): avoid over-iterating with `--heads`, `--tags`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> When `show-ref` is combined with the `--heads` or `--tags` options, it can avoid iterating parts of a repository's references that it doesn't care about.
>
> But it doesn't take advantage of this potential optimization.
> When this command was introduced back in [358ddb6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/358ddb62cfd03bba1ca2f1ae8e81b9510f42ea9a) (Add , 2006-09-15, Git v1.4.4-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/58a1e0e83bcdbf063fb708ee9a8a563c0aa14f87)) (Add "[`git show-ref`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c0c9d35e27e777d117362f6e96f433eb2b55bf76/Documentation/git-show-ref.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-ref))</sup> builtin command, 2006-09-15), `for_each_ref_in()` did exist.
> But since most repositories don't have many (any?) references that aren't branches or tags already, this makes little difference in practice.
>
> Though for repositories with a large imbalance of branches and tags (or, more likely in the case of server operators, many hidden references), this can make quite a difference.
> Take, for example, a repository with 500,000 "hidden" references (all of the form "`refs/__hidden__/N`"), and a single branch:
>
> ```
> git commit --allow-empty -m "base" &&
> seq 1 500000 | sed 's,\(.*\),create refs/__hidden__/\1 HEAD,' |
>   git update-ref --stdin &&
> git pack-refs --all
> ```
>
> Outputting the existence of that single branch currently takes on the order of ~50ms on my machine.
> The vast majority of this time is wasted iterating through references that we know we're going to discard.
>
> Instead, teach `show-ref` that it can iterate just "`refs/heads`" and/or "`refs/tags`" when given `--heads` and/or `--tags`, respectively.
>
> A few small interesting things to note:
>
> - When given either option, we can avoid the general-purpose `for_each_ref()` call altogether, since we know that it won't give us any references that we wouldn't filter out already.
> - We can make two separate calls to `for_each_fullref_in()` (and avoid, say, the more specialized `for_each_fullref_in_prefixes()`, since we know that the set of references enumerated by each is disjoint, so we'll never see the same reference appear in both calls.
> - We have to use the "fullref" variant (instead of just `for_each_branch_ref()` and `for_each_tag_ref()`), since we expect fully-qualified reference names to appear in `show-ref`'s output.
>
> When either of `heads_only` or `tags_only` is set, we can eliminate the `strcmp()` calls in `builtin/show-ref.c::show_ref()` altogether, since we know that `show_ref()` will never see a non-branch or tag reference.
>
> Unfortunately, we can't use `for_each_fullref_in_prefixes()` to enhance `show-ref`'s pattern matching, since `show-ref` patterns match on the *suffix* (e.g., the pattern "foo" shows "`refs/heads/foo`", "`refs/tags/foo`", and etc, not "`foo/*`").
>
> Nonetheless, in our synthetic example above, this provides a significant speed-up ("git" is roughly v2.36, "`git.compile`" is this patch):
>
> ```
> $ hyperfine -N 'git show-ref --heads' 'git.compile show-ref --heads'
> Benchmark 1: git show-ref --heads
>   Time (mean ± σ):      49.9 ms ±   6.2 ms    [User: 45.6 ms, System: 4.1 ms]
>   Range (min … max):    46.1 ms …  73.6 ms    43 runs
>
> Benchmark 2: git.compile show-ref --heads
>   Time (mean ± σ):       2.8 ms ±   0.4 ms    [User: 1.4 ms, System: 1.2 ms]
>   Range (min … max):     1.3 ms …   5.6 ms    957 runs
>
> Summary
>   'git.compile show-ref --heads' ran
>    18.03 ± 3.38 times faster than 'git show-ref --heads'
> ```