# Commit hash does not exist in git log

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I was exploring GitHub projects using git. Some things don't make sense to me.

For example in *Opencv* I can checkout to commit `539f065446a993825d61dddc5d9dc72ae54d7a29` (which is version 4.2.0). However when I use `git rev-list --all` to view the list of all commits, I don't find this hash (539f...).

Why is this the case? This is happening for many tagged commits.

Comment: If you need the hash of the tagged commit, you can use the following code snippet from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796522/git-tag-list-display-commit-sha1-hashes): `git show-ref --tags -d`

Comment: try following command: `git log --full-history`. look also git-docs [git-scm.com/docs/git-log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

Comment: Are you sure that `539f...` is actually a *commit* hash, and not an annotated tag object? (`git cat-file -t 539f065446a993825d61dddc5d9dc72ae54d7a29` will tell you the object's type.)

Comment: In my case the first commit I see with cmd: `git log --reverse --full-history -- $file` doesn't show my commit hash, but `git log --grep=pattern $file` - shows it so i'm also puzzled where my commit is getting lost in the `git log` history command ? ...

Answer (score 1):

As @torek points out, in this case `539f065446a993825d61dddc5d9dc72ae54d7a29` is not a commit hash but a ref to  annotated tag object (vs lightweight tags) so it is not among commits refs. For this exact `opencv` project

```
$ cat .git/refs/tags/4.2.0
539f065446a993825d61dddc5d9dc72ae54d7a29
```

You can see the tagged commit ref and tag's ref as @flaxel points (the second is tag's related commit hash)

```
$ git show-ref --tags -d
...
539f065446a993825d61dddc5d9dc72ae54d7a29 refs/tags/4.2.0
bda89a6469aa79ecd8713967916bd754bff1d931 refs/tags/4.2.0^{}
...

$ git cat-file -t 539f065446a993825d61dddc5d9dc72ae54d7a29
tag

$ git cat-file -t bda89a6469aa79ecd8713967916bd754bff1d931
commit

$ git show-ref --head
0052d46b8e33c7bfe0e1450e4bff28b88f455570 HEAD
0052d46b8e33c7bfe0e1450e4bff28b88f455570 refs/heads/master
...
539f065446a993825d61dddc5d9dc72ae54d7a29 refs/tags/4.2.0
...
```

Annotated tag objects have extra meta data (tagger's name, email, date, message)

```
$ git show 539f065446a993825d61dddc5d9dc72ae54d7a29
tag 4.2.0
Tagger: Alexander Alekhin <alexander.alekhin@intel.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 20 16:44:16 2019 +0300

OpenCV 4.2.0

commit bda89a6469aa79ecd8713967916bd754bff1d931 (tag: 4.2.0)
Author: Alexander Alekhin <alexander.alekhin@intel.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 20 16:44:16 2019 +0300

    release: OpenCV 4.2.0
...
```

Annotated tag can be created with

```
git tag -a v1.0 -m "Adding tag 1.0 (tag's message)"
```