# How can I only display the hash values ​of tags and commits from a Git repository on the Powershell?

Tags: git, powershell, tags, commit

I want to see the hash values ​​of the tags and then the commits from a git repository. So separated from each other but really only the hash values, i.e. without description or anything.

Comment: Please may you write the question in English?

Comment: And see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8796647/6309

Comment: Yes, definitely,
I only want to see the hash values ​​of the tags and then the commits from a Git repository. So separated from each other but really only the hash values, i.e. without description or anything.

Can someone please help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about powershell, but in a unix shell it's

```
git for-each-ref refs/tags --format='%(objectname) %(*objectname)'
```