# Get GitHub tag messages (or tags in general) through GitHub's REST API v3 without knowing the SHA

Tags: python, github-api, pygithub

I'm trying to access a tag's message (essentially the image below) for use in an autoupdater section of a program I'm making.

[Essentially trying to use Github APIs to get the region in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4Qnh.png)

However, in order to access the tag's message, you need to first get the SHA. Thanks to the way my code works, I can't take the easy way out and hardcode the SHA, I'll need to actively request the tag through the servers itself. And that's where my problem lies - I have no idea how I can obtain either the tag or its SHA from GitHub's servers.

To help find it, I can still get the info surrounding it, like the commit it's tied to, the ref that I had to make when making the tag via code, the name of the file, and pretty much everything short of the tag's SHA and Message.

I've tried to:

- Get the tag using the SHA of the commit it's tied to (Got a 404)
- Request a list of all the refs in the project, found the ref the tag is tied to, and accessing it that way (also didn't work)
- Find a way to get its Tag object variant, and using that to get to the actual tag (didn't hold any actual data that could be used to get to the tag)
- Use the info from the commit the tag is tied to in order to obtain the SHA and/or the tag data itself (no dice)

Is there anything I can do about this? I've been accessing the GitHub API using [PyGithub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub).

None of the answers to [Git Tag list, display commit sha1 hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796522/git-tag-list-display-commit-sha1-hashes) help me because I'm using an entirly different set of commands than what's given in the git command.

Comment: Any takers? It would be nice even if I got confirmation that this is impossible... also thanks jonrsharpe for editing the question :)