# Github: show tags in commits history

Tags: git, github, tags, commit, bitbucket

I have a repository on github, and another on bitbucket. Both have some tags.

The thing is, bitbucket shows next to commits the tag they relate to, while github doesn't. Is there a way to show tags next to commit history? :)

Cheers.

Comment: Why did you accept that answer? It doesn't answer your question at all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064499/how-to-list-all-git-tags

Comment: I do not understand why GitHub did not implement this yet. You can see the tags in the commit history using this web browser extension: https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github

Answer (score -9, accepted):

To show the tags that contain a commit (i.e. tags the precede a commit):

```
git tag --contains <commit>
```