# How to I configure git to always sign tags?

Tags: git, git-config, git-tag

Few repositories I use required all tags to be signed and sometimes I forget to add the `-s` to `git tag`, or even worse, I create the tag using a git GUI that has no idea about tags.

Is there a way to configure GIT to always sign tags?

I mention that I tried adding the below hack(s) to `.gitconfig` but it didn't had any effect, tags were created without signing unless I mentioned manually the -s on the cli.

```
[alias]
tag = tag -s

[tag]
forceSignAnnotated = true

[commit]
gpgsign = true
```

Comment: Maybe it's an option under `[tag]` in config, like with `[commit]`?

Comment: there is hubflow option in git where u can create tag and all automatically once you finish your branch

Comment: Please make sure to also add the `user.signingkey` to your git config (gpg key id). eg. `git config --global user.signingkey 0A1B2C3D`.

Comment: `alias.tag` can't work because aliases that hide existing Git commands are ignored.

Comment: With Git 2.23 (Q3 2019), check out [`git config tag.gpgSign true`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56979390/6309)!

Answer (score 39):

Update for Git 2.23 (Q3 2019), [you now have `git config tag.gpgSign true`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56979390/6309)!

---

Original answer (June 2018)

While there is no "signed by default" mode for git tag, [the documentation mentions](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#_configuration):

> Once you have a private key to sign with, you can configure Git to use it for signing things by setting the user.signingkey config setting.

```
git config --global user.signingkey 0A46826A
```

> By default, `git tag` in sign-with-default mode (`-s`) will use your committer identity (of the form `Your Name <your@email.address>`) to find a key.
>   If you want to use a different default key, you can specify it in the repository configuration as follows:

```
[user]
    signingKey = <gpg-keyid>
```

Note: if you create your tag with the `-m` option (`tag -m "a comment" myTag`), that make them *annotated*.

From [`git tag` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#_description):

> If `-m <msg>` or `-F <file>` is given and `-a`, `-s`, and `-u <keyid>` are absent, `-a` is implied.

So you could:

- *not* define an alias for git tag (not `add -s`)
- set from terminal `git config tag.forceSignAnnotated true`

That way, any `git tag -m "a comment" myTag` will trigger the gpgpSign.
Only for annotated tag, but since [those are ones which are supposed to be not just local to your repo but also pushed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1064505/6309), that should be enough.

Answer (score 5):

```
[alias]
tag = tag -s
```

You cannot override a builtin command with an alias. Use a different
name for the alias:

```
[alias]
stag = tag -s
```

As for

```
[tag]
forceSignAnnotated = true
```

this forces **annotated** tags to be signed but you have to create
annotated tags with `git tag -a` which is not much better that `git tag -s`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the alias directive, but your [tag] and [commit] seem correct, and those are working for me.  Just make sure (like Bjoern Rennhak) said that user.signingkey is also defined and using a valid key.  Also check your git version, as 'forceSignAnnotated' was only made available as of Git version 2.9.0.