# How do I configure git to PGP sign my tags by default (not my commits)

Tags: git

I currently have the following `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[gpg]
    program = /usr/local/bin/krgpg
[commit]
    gpgSign = true
[tag]
    forceSignAnnotated = true
```

A commit requires me to sign using PGP:

```
git commit -m "Add package.json"
Krypton ▶ Requesting git commit signature from phone
```

However, I want to only sign my tags, and skip signing commits.

**Question: Is there any way for me configure git to sign just my tags**

I mean, short of aliasing:

```
$ git alias.tag 'tag -s'
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With Git 2.23 (Q3 2019), you now have a new `tag.gpgSign` configuration variable, which turns "`git tag -a`" into "`git tag -s`"! You can enable it by default with:

```bash
git config --global tag.gpgSign true
```

See [commit 1c6b565](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c6b565f896c27dc7c52aa3af9c7dcfc7934e8fe) (05 Jun 2019) by [Tigran Mkrtchyan (`tigran1999`)](https://github.com/tigran1999).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 492d7a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/492d7a553c8a097ad66f4a39acf187e7f02a4117), 09 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### tag: add tag.gpgSign config option to force all tags be GPG-signed

As many CI/CD tools don't allow to control command line options when
executing `git tag` command, a default value in the configuration file
will allow to enforce tag signing if required.

> The new config-file option `tag.gpgSign` is added to define default behavior
> of tag signings.
> To override default behavior the command line option `-s`, `--sign` and `--no-sign` can be used:
>
> ```
> $ git tag -m "commit message"
> ```
>
> will generate a GPG signed tag if `tag.gpgSign` option is true, while
>
> ```
> $ git tag --no-sign -m "commit message"
> ```
>
> will skip the signing step.

The [`git config` for tag](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1c6b565f896c27dc7c52aa3af9c7dcfc7934e8fe/Documentation/config/tag.txt#L11-L17) now includes:

> ### `tag.gpgSign`:
>
> A boolean to specify whether all tags should be GPG signed.
>
> Use of this option when running in an automated script can result in a large number of tags being signed.
> It is therefore convenient to use an agent to avoid typing your gpg passphrase several times.
>
> Note that this option doesn't affects tag signing behavior enabled by "`-u <keyid>`" or "`--local-user=<keyid>`" options.

---

A failed "[`git tag -s`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/05c5a6db805c2636001c8b41dcb38e5df10cb113/Documentation/git-tag.txt#L64)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#Documentation/git-tag.txt--s))</sup> did not necessarily result in an error depending on the crypto backend, which has been corrected with Git 2.44.0 (Q1 2024), [rc1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad1a6695454c6fd922617b03ebb5678841a17db5).

See [commit 6931049](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6931049c32ca0271ba95dcd0f197100d22c8d844), [commit abfbff6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/abfbff61efc4d91dc964eb2360760fa640ad0f0f) (07 Feb 2024) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 05c5a6d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/05c5a6db805c2636001c8b41dcb38e5df10cb113), 12 Feb 2024)</sup>

> ### [`tag`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/abfbff61efc4d91dc964eb2360760fa640ad0f0f): fix `sign_buffer()` call to create a signed tag
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Sergey Kosukhin</sup>

> The command "[`git tag -s`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/abfbff61efc4d91dc964eb2360760fa640ad0f0f/Documentation/git-tag.txt#L64)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#Documentation/git-tag.txt--s))</sup> internally calls `sign_buffer()` to make a cryptographic signature using the chosen backend like GPG and SSH.
>
> The internal helper functions used by "[`git tag`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/abfbff61efc4d91dc964eb2360760fa640ad0f0f/Documentation/git-tag.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag))</sup> implementation seem to use a negative return values are errors, zero or positive return values are not" convention, and there are places (e.g., `verify_tag()` that calls `gpg_verify_tag()`) that these internal helper functions translate return values that signal errors to conform to this convention, but `do_sign()` that calls `sign_buffer()` forgets to do so.
>
> Fix it, so that a failed call to `sign_buffer()` that can return the exit status from `pipe_command()` will not be overlooked.