# List all git tags with their annotations?

Tags: git, git-tag

I know how to [list all git tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064499/how-to-list-all-git-tags). But - what if I want to list them and print each tag's annotation?

Can I do this with git itself, or do I need a shell loop with git show

Comment: Use `git for-each-ref`, plus a bit of testing because some tags aren't annotated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2119135/7976758

Answer (score 1):

I use this alias myself, maybe adapt it to your needs :

```
git config --global alias.tl 'git for-each-ref --sort=-authordate --format="%(contents:subject)  %(objectname:short)  (%(refname:short))" refs/tags'

# then just
git tl
```

Note that it is expecting *annotated* tags.